# How to insert data from a table row by row and insert into another row by row

Tags: sql-server, datatables

I have two tables (A, B) with autogenerated id both of them and i need that when I make an insert to one (A) automatically puts the id of that one in a column of the other (B.Aid)

I've tried a trigger, a cursor that called a procedure ...

Comment: u have to show what u have tried yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may serve the purpose

```
-- DROP TABLE A
-- DROP TABLE B

CREATE TABLE A (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE B (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Name VARCHAR(50), Aid INT)
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerToAddAutoIntoTableB ON A
AFTER INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO B (Name,Aid) 
    SELECT i.Name,i.id
    FROM inserted i

GO
INSERT INTO A (Name) values ('A1')
INSERT INTO A (Name) values ('A2')
INSERT INTO A (Name) values ('A3')
GO
SELECT * FROM A
SELECT * FROM B
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me to find the awnser. I made a trigger with a cursor of the inserted rows and inside put the update

Answer (score 0):

use the `INSERT INTO SELECT` function

```
INSERT INTO dbo.eexample(street, city, state, zip_code) 
SELECT
    street,
    city,
    state,
    zip_code
FROM
    dbo.anotherexample
where
 ORDER BY anotherexample.Id
```

Comment: this is not going to work because i need them to be in order of insert, like row by row

Comment: Use ORDER BY clause. For example ORDER BY table_b.Id ASC